# When compiling for the "Store Upload" apk under Cordova command line

Tags: android, cordova

Before I give the following command

```
cordova build --release
```

I read that I must put the following inside my AndroidMainfest.xml

```
android:debuggable="false"
```

to make it look like this

```
<application android:debuggable="false"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
 android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
 android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Is it necessary to put this attribute     android:debuggable="false"  ?

If I do that, I get an error when I run the command and it stops the compiling

```
cordova build --release
```

But if I do not, it compiles with no errors.